# How to do in-place polar coordinates transform with numpy a la numexpr

Tags: python, caching, numpy, numexpr

Numexpr is a python module that enables jitting some expressions for working with numpy arrays. Now, it would be cool if it allowed me to do:

```
ne.evaluate( """
    r = y 
    cita = 2*pi*x/x_span
    nx = CENTER_X + cos( cita ) * r 
    ny = CENTER_Y + sin( cita ) * r
    """, local_dict={ 'x': xy_array[:,0],
                  'y': xy_array[:,1],
                  'x_span': x_span,
                  'y_span': y_span,
                  'pi': 3.141592,
                  'nx': nxy[:0],
                  'ny': nxy[:1],
                  'CENTER_X': ...,
                  'CENTER_Y': ...,            
                }, 
     )
```

where I could re-use the calculated value of `cita` to calculate both `nx` and `ny`. Also, because I would have to retrieve x and y once and they are one after the other in memory, I would also get less cache misses; same goes for writing of `nx` and `ny`. However, as far as I understand, as it stands now, this kind of code is not possible with Numexpr.

So, my questions:

Is there is a more advanced thing for python+numpy that could do this? (Some super-set of numexpr)

Or, am I wrong and this could simply be done with numpy and numexpr?

NOTE 1: I know that I could implement this little function in quite a few ways in C/C++/whatever, or that I could care less about performance and do hacks that involve numpy with or without numexpr.

NOTE 2: I know about [weave](http://www.scipy.org/Weave), but I put it in the sack of "uncool, unmaintained solutions that would involve messing with C".

Comment: I'm confused, are you just trying to convert from cartesian to polar coordinates?

Comment: I used the conversion to polar coordinates as an example. I'm just looking for a general way to do this kind of things.

Comment: Cython? It doesn't look possible with numexpr from what I can see. You could also look into calling Julia from python? Not sure what you're looking for. . .

Comment: Thank you @reptilicus. Your comment reinforces my opinion about numexpr not being fit for this. My concrete problem was solved using an inefficient work-around, but this question was about if there was a way of having something that would allow to implement calculations by a "dag" or local variables a-ala-numexpr, with Numpy and Python.